# what is the difference between feature detection and cascade classifiers in opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, feature-detection

The following feature detector types are supported by opencv 2.4.9:

```
"FAST" – FastFeatureDetector
"STAR" – StarFeatureDetector
"SIFT" – SIFT (nonfree module)
"SURF" – SURF (nonfree module)
"ORB" – ORB
"BRISK" – BRISK
"MSER" – MSER
"GFTT" – GoodFeaturesToTrackDetector
"HARRIS" – GoodFeaturesToTrackDetector with Harris detector enabled
"Dense" – DenseFeatureDetector
"SimpleBlob" – SimpleBlobDetector
```

The following cascade classifiers types are supported by opencv 2.4.9:

```
Haar Feature based Cascade Classifier for Object Detection
Lbp feature based Cascade Classifier for Object Detection
HOG feature based Cascade Classifier for Object Detection
```

After finding the object which method returns object's orientation in the realtime image? 
Which method supports multiple object detection in the realtime image? 
Whats the main difference between feature detection and cascade classifiers in object finding technology?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: in general, feature extraction detects (and sometimes describes) features. While classification methods use features to classify an image whether it is some kind of (often trained) object or not.

Comment: In opencv, a classifier is a detector who is based on features.

Comment: feature detectors only detect salient points, not objects.

Comment: If both method have features, then they are same?

Comment: they are not the same, they even have different goals. A feature is a property of the image or the object while classification is to interpret features/properties. So classification and object detection are at least one level above feature detection since they (might) use features.